# Connection and unknown errors in FlutterFire Messaging (iOS Only)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented FlutterFire Messaging with the `subscribeToTopic` method, as the snippet below:

```dart
final _topics = ['topicName'];

Future<void> subscribeTopics() async {
  for (final topic in _topics) {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);
  }
}

Future<void> unsubscribeTopics() async {
  for (final topic in _topics) {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
  }
}
```

And everything is fine in debug mode, but in my Crashlytics I'm receiving some reports about it (iOS only):

- [firebase_messaging/unknown] The request timed out
- [firebase_messaging/unknown] An unknown error has occurred
- [firebase_messaging/unknown] A data connection is not currently allowed
- [firebase_messaging/unknown] The Internet connection appears to be offline

All the errors appears to be about internet connection, so my question is: "Should I validate the user connection before use FCM or the lib is ready to deal with it but only in Android?"

Crashlytics Stacktrace

```dart
Non-fatal Exception: FlutterError
0  ???                            0x0 MethodChannelFirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic + 368 (method_channel_messaging.dart:368)
1  ???                            0x0 Messaging.subscribeTopics + 40 (messaging.dart:40)
2  ???                            0x0 Messaging.observeMessaging + 22 (messaging.dart:22)
```

Comment: You should disable App if there is no internet since it depends on it. check https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

Comment: Thanks, but you know if it is documented anywhere?

Comment: but there is no logic to use it without internet, right. Something like Connection Lost alert would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general error so you shouldn't worry about it. When the internet connection restores the method will hopefully restart itself. You should also consider the case that It might generate an error while the app is in the background.

You can use `try` `catch` block to avoid these messages in your crashlytics dashboard.

```dart
final _topics = ['topicName'];

Future<void> subscribeTopics() async {
  try {
    for (final topic in _topics) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);
    }
  } on FirebaseException {
    // do nothing
  }
}

Future<void> unsubscribeTopics() async {
  try {
    for (final topic in _topics) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
    }
  } on FirebaseException {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

**Note** It will also ignore all other error messages too. In that case
You can handle it otherwise

```dart
final _topics = ['topicName'];

Future<void> subscribeTopics() async {
  try {
    for (final topic in _topics) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(topic);
    }
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'unknown') {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  }
}

Future<void> unsubscribeTopics() async {
  try {
    for (final topic in _topics) {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.unsubscribeFromTopic(topic);
    }
  } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'unknown') {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```